# Pass data from db to JS object

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm getting a JSON from ASP.NET MVC controller and I want to use it inside a JS variable. I'm sure `data` is not null but it says `myVar` is null, here is my code :

```
        var myVar = null
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var myurl = "/SomeController/SomeAction";



            $.get(myurl, null, function (data) {
                myVar = data;
            });
        });
        var cy = cytoscape({

          container: document.getElementById("cy"),
          elements: myVar

        });

console.log(myVar); // returns null
```

How can I pass the content of `data` to `cy` object correctly? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)